# Controlling Hyperlink target in exported .pdf from Reporting Service

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, hyperlink, reporting

I have a problem regarding Reporting Service and the exported .pdf functionality - how do I control the Hyperlinks it creates and their target? The reason is, I use the generated .pdf as our print-functionality (of messages) in a web application (embedded in a portal). The problem occurs when the message contains a Link.

Reporting Service automatically creates a Hyperlink but sets no TARGET which means that the link simply opens up in the window where it's displayed. My question:

Is there any way to control the Target of all links in a Reporting Services generated .pdf? If not, can I disable the links entirely making them non-clickable?

Kind regards
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is possible. When exporting to PDF any text prefixed with `http:\\` or `www.` seems to be converted to links automatically.

A rather hacky solution could be to set up a calculated field to remove any prefixes

```
=Replace(Replace(Fields!YourField.Value,"http:\\",""),"www.","")
```

That will convert [www.google.com](http://www.google.com/) or http://www.google.com to plain google.com and it won't be clickable when you export to pdf.

Comment: Although not quite what I wanted, this could hackfix the problem.

PS. Sorry for late reply ;)